# C# - How to send information to multiple [FromForm]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, http-post

I have an endpoint like so:

```
[HttpPost("DoWork")]
public async Task<ActionResult> DoWork([FromForm] string name, [FromForm] string uri) {
    ...
}
```

From the other end how do I package and send that data, would it look something like this?

```
public void MyMethod(string name, string uri) {
    Dictionary<string, string> packet = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    packet.Add("name", name);
    packet.Add("uri", uri);

    var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(packet), UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished it by using a RestRequest and adding in each parameter before sending the request:

```
RestClient rC = new RestClient(apiUrl);
RestRequest rr = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
rr.AddParameter("name", name);
rr.AddParameter("uri", uri);
RestResponse response = (RestResponse)await rC.ExecutePostAsync(rr);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create a view model

```
public class ViewModel
{
public string Name {get; set;}
public string Uri {get; set;}
}
```

and action

```
[HttpPost("DoWork")]
public async Task<ActionResult> DoWork([FromBody] ViewModel viewModel)
{
    ...
}
```

IMHO, the way you created content, you don't need [FromForm], try [FromBody] instead